# Download and installation of d3web

Tags: expert-system, d3web

I am new to d3web. However, after I downloaded the latest software from your website and unzip it:

```
~/study/d3web$ ls 
d3web Quickstart.pdf  doc.zip  lib.zip  sources.zip
```

It contains 3 zip files. There is no `bin/` directory as described [here](https://www.d3web.de/Wiki.jsp?page=D3web-KnowWE%20Quickstart).

I want to quickly get it started and test the Printer demo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I adapted the quickstart page now to fit our current distribution package. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, and I am sorry for the confusion. With the last release of d3web-KnowWE we changed the distribution script but haven't yet updated the documentation on the linked page to reflect that. The distribution zip now contains 3 folders, d3web, KnowWE and Licenses.

The folder **d3web** contains just the core libraries to be embedded in other software, you probably won't use them at the beginning. After creating knowledge bases in KnowWE you could use these libraries to run that knowledge base without KnowWE in your own software/app.

The folder **KnowWE** contains the actual wiki that you probably expect. Besides the zips for documentation and sources, it also contains the **KnowWE-Tomcat.zip**. Extract this and you get the bin folder and all the rest that is described in the Quickstart.